# Twilio SMS to Function and Webhook

Tags: function, sms, webhooks, sendgrid, forward

I was using Sendgrid to forward my SMSs to email. At a later time, I synced Twilio with a CRM that we use and the CRM took ownership adding their own webhook when the message comes in. Is there a way to still use the function I had (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/forward-incoming-sms-messages-to-email-with-node-js-sendgrid-and-twilio-functions.html) and add the CRM webhook at the same time so I can see the SMSs in both, the CRM and email?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

What you could do with this is use the Function to forward the SMS to email and send it to the CRM.

To do this you would take the CRM URL and make the request to it from the Function using all the data sent into the event from Twilio. This should log the data in the CRM and keep your original email behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is my same question just worded different. How to take the CRM URL and adding it to the function is exactly my question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have not tried anything because I don't know where to insert the webhook into the function

Comment: You need to make an HTTP request to your CRM URL. So you’ll need to write some code to make that HTTP request in JavaScript from the function alongside the code that makes the request to SendGrid to send the email. Does that give you an idea what you need to do?